# Postal money order for Schengen visa for Germany

Tags: germany, schengen-visas

I am applying for a Schengen visa by mail. It is not clear anywhere what name I should put in the "Pay To" field of the Postal money order for visa fees. Same with the Address field. I am applying to the New York consulate.

I am considering writing "German missions in the United States" in the Pay to section.

Comment: If all else fails, you could make it payable to "Bearer" or "Cash" or leave the field blank.  This guarantees that they will be able to cash it, though it does mean that if the money order is stolen, the thief could also cash it.

Comment: As for the Address field, AFAIK it's optional and there is no harm in leaving it blank.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the consulate?

Comment: I called them at (202) 298-4000, but I reached them after hours on Friday. The person on the other end was not from the visa section so was unable to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their postal address is on their [website](https://www.germany.info/us-en/embassy-consulates/newyork):

> Consulate General of the Federal Republic of Germany, 871 United Nations Plaza, New York, NY 10017, USA.

As far as who to make money order out to, I found no info of that on their site. That being said, if you do use a money order and make it payable to "bearer" you are assuming the risk of it being stolen and cashed by the thief. I'd recommend [contacting](https://www.germany.info/us-en/embassy-consulates/newyork/kontakt-formular-new-york?preSelectedId=1034414) the consulate about it, they are very responsive by contact form and email from  my experience.